# Java StackOverflowError while recursively building an array from a binary search tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, rebuild, stack-overflow

I'm trying to balance a BST by first building an array (inorder) and then rebuild the entire tree from my array.

I have:

```
 public void toArray(E[] a) {
  toArray(root, a, 0);
 }

 /*
  * Adds all elements from the tree rooted at n in inorder to the array a
  * starting at a[index].
  * Returns the index of the last inserted element + 1 (the first empty
  * position in a).
  */
 private int toArray(BinaryNode<E> node, E[] a, int index) {
  if (node.left != null) {
   index = toArray(node, a, index);
  }

  a[index] = node.element;
  index++;

  if (node.right != null) {
   index = toArray(node, a, index);
  }

  return index;
 }
```

and:

```
bst.toArray(b);
```

I was hoping that this would build an array inorder. But i get StackOverflowError. As I understand that is probably due to infinite recursion but I really can't see it.

The error occurs on this line:

```
index = toArray(node, a, index);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
index = toArray(node, a, index);
```

You wanted to write `node.left` or `node.right`?

Comment: Off cause =) sorry to waste your time. Thanks!

Comment: Thought i did? I clicked the check-mark and it said wait for seven more minutes so i did, clicked it again and it turned green. Have i missed something?

Comment: How comes people don't upvote the question itself? This drives me crazy on SO.  I never, ever, upvote an answer without upvoting the question itself.  If the answer is worthy a vote, the question definitely is too.

Answer (score 1):

here it is:

```
if (node.left != null) {
    index = toArray(node, a, index);
}
```

you've probably wanted to do something with `index` (increment for example) or with the node (like, `node = node.left`) (I didn't investigate your algorithm, just general suggestions).